# Настроить запрет в htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, https

Есть домен `https://site.ru/` и есть поддомен `https://sub.site.ru/`. Как в htaccess настроить запрет 403 для поддомена на посещение, кроме ссылок с домена?

Что пробовал я сделать на поддомене:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www.)?site\.ru(/)?
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(.*)\.site\.ru(/)?
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www.)?site\.ru(/)?
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.*)\.site\.ru(/)?
RewriteRule .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|html|htm|css|js)$ – [F]
```

Comment: Сервер у вас apache? А то может статику nginx отдает?

Comment: Сервер nginx, но я отключил его для всех файлов.

Comment: .htaccess только для apache.

Comment: Это понятно, мой htaccess закрывает 403 все переходы на поддомен. Мне нужно открыть только с доменна?